# Is it good idea to use mysql stored procedure in codeigniter large application?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing a large codeigniter application, I think i will use the stored procedure in mysql, Is it good idea to use the stored procedure in CI?

Do i face any problem in future with active records of CI?
Am i doing right or wrong?

[Codeigniter DB errors after stored procedure call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486720/codeigniter-db-errors-after-stored-procedure-call)

I am facing this problem at every time.

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's a "holly war" question. You can google all pros and cons but in general, if you have no special needs and it's not a pet-project or proof-of-stored-procedures-concept avoid to use stored procedures.

The reasons are:

- maintenance. You can easy forget to update procedure when you make some changes to data structure.
- documentation. Sometime, especially new employees don't know about what exactly that procedure does or need slightly different data from procedure and write their own, so in a while you get a mess of procedures.
- preformance. If you use prepared statements they are 'compiled' by query parser and optimizer and then stored in cache. On each call query manager just execute that compiled query with new data, so you will not gain any extra performance benefit (I'm talking about 10k hits per minute x N queries to db in each request)

I may be wrong in my conviction, but for prototyping or fast growing project stored procedures has no sense. I experimented with them and found them nice sometimes, but nothing more. It looks like in mysql stored procedures was added because they exists in Oracle and PostgreSQL

Conclusion:

Increasing code complexity doesn't worth benefits (if any).

You can also ask question or look for similar on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
Maybe someone with high reputation will make any suggestion?

Nice article about stored procedures in general available at [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html), it's a bit old but in general has nice thoughts.